# Making an Access List Box Editable from a Form

Tags: ms-access

I have a series of 2 list-boxes and a combo box in an Access form that are cascading. I would like to be able to edit the listboxes from the form by double-clicking on the specific value. I've changed allow value list edits to Yes. I'm sure there's something I need to add to the double-click event but I've searched around and can't find the code. I'm brand new to Access so any help would be appreciated.

**cmbSuppliers**

Row Source

```
SELECT tblSuppliers.[Supplier ID], tblSuppliers.[Company Name] FROM tblSuppliers ORDER BY tblSuppliers.[Supplier ID];
```

Event

```
Private Sub cmbSuppliers_AfterUpdate()
    Me.lstEquip.Requery
End Sub
```

**lstEquip**

Row Source

```
SELECT tblEquipment.[Equipment ID], tblEquipment.Description, tblEquipment.[Supplier ID] FROM tblEquipment WHERE (((tblEquipment.[Supplier ID])=[Forms]![frmInventory]![cmbSuppliers])) ORDER BY tblEquipment.[Equipment ID];
```

Events

```
Private Sub lstEquip_AfterUpdate()
    Me.lstParts.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub lstEquip_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub
```

**lstParts**

Row Source

```
SELECT tblParts.[Part ID], tblParts.Description, tblParts.Quantity, tblParts.[Mininum Quantity] FROM tblParts WHERE (((tblParts.[Equipment ID])=[Forms]![frmInventory]![lstEquip])) ORDER BY tblParts.[Part ID], tblParts.Description, tblParts.Quantity, tblParts.[Mininum Quantity];
```

**frmInventory**

Event

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.lstParts.Requery
End Sub
```

I included the row source information for cmbSuppliers even though I'm not sure if that's helpful. I'm only trying to make it possible to edit values in the two listboxes.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Allow Value List Edits" property? If so, then you have to create a Form where you edit those list items, and then use that form to modify the values in the list. This Microsoft article shows how to do that: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-list-of-choices-by-using-a-list-box-or-combo-box-HA010113052.aspx#_Toc356995228

Comment: Okay so I saw that article but I'd really like to be able to directly edit the list without opening a different form. There are 4 fields in the list and sometimes it will just be necessary to update one of them. Is there a way to do this without using a separate form?

Comment: Please post the sql for both boxes and for the form.

Comment: Okay I editted the post- is that what you were talking about or did you need something different?

Comment: If you want to change a field / column other than the bound column, I can't see any way around a form or update query. I wondered if you were the same table to get the combo data and for data entry.

Comment: Okay so I'll essentially have one form as an inventory display and another form with identical information for the users to edit the data?

Comment: Unless you want to switch to a subform, which might be a lor easier.